# Compare if subnet is in IP range, in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, comparison, ip-address, subnet, netmask

I have a set of subnets with labeled descriptions in a csv file. I need to assign these descriptions to the Data Probe ranges that these subnets belong to in another csv file.

Given a subnet with an ipaddress `34.0.0.0` and netmask `255.255.0.0`,
I want to check if the subnet is in the range `34.163.83.230-34.163.83.230`

I have considered creating a range  from the subnet's ip and net mask and comparing it to the Data Probe ranges. I haven't been able to find out if this would yield the correct answer.

I cannot use the latest version of Python (this has to work with an application running python 2.7), so the `ipaddress` module is not an option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `socket` module provides `inet_aton`, which will convert your addresses to bitstrings.  You can then convert them to integers using `struct.unpack`, mask using `&`, and use integer comparison:

```
from socket import inet_aton
from struct import unpack

def atol(a):
    return unpack(">L", inet_aton(a))[0]

addr = atol("30.44.230.0")
mask = atol("255.255.0.0")
lo = atol("32.44.230.0")
hi = atol("32.44.230.255")
prefix = addr & mask

print lo <= prefix <= hi
```

Comment: Thanks. I used this to make comparisons I needed. I just wanted to let other people know this is not the full solution to checking the subnet to the range.